# iOS development database options

Tags: php, mysql, ios

My background is in PHP but I have recently started developing an iOS app. I need to store and retrieve values in some sort of database (where I would usually use MySQL in PHP).

For example, supposing the app displayed a list of pubs in a town, the user would be able to choose their town and view a list of all the pubs. This would allow me to add/remove pubs on the app (by editing the database) without requiring an app update.

Is this something I can still use MySQL for, or are there other preferred methods when it comes to iOS development?

Comment: Are you talking about a local database embedded in your app or a remote database that your app access via the Internet?

Comment: Then the answer by @Greg is reasonable. The fact that you are developing an iOS app is irrelevant. Your server should be able to reply to requests from any kind of client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can still use PHP and MySQL to do that. 
The best solution is create a Web Service with PHP and MySQL as a backend.
You can expose web service and consume it from the app. You can even create web site to use the same web service (or database directly) so you can amend the database via website and all iOS users will see the changes on the app.

There is plenty of tutorial about this topic. This is a good one [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)